# Hover-over and show change background-color h1

Tags: html, css

I have an image with an embedded title h1. The whole image is clickable a href. When the user hovers over h1 then the background-color of h1 title changes. I would like that the background-color of h1 title changes also when user hovers over the image, so not directly on the h1 title. Possible?

```css
.sh1 h1:hover {
 background-color: #000;
 -moz-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 transition: .6s ease-in-out;
}

.sh1 {
    background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/140/180/any);
 margin:30px;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
}

.bt {
    background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/140/380/any);
 margin:30px;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
}

.mt {
    background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/240/580/any);
 margin:30px;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
}



.mt h1:hover {
 background-color: red;
 -moz-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 transition: .6s ease-in-out;
}

.bt h1:hover {
 background-color: blue;
 -moz-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 transition: .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="bt"><h1>BIG TITLE</h1></a>
<a href="#" class="mt"><h1>MEDIUM TITLE</h1></a>
<a href="#" class="sh1"><h1>SMALL H1</h1></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css selectors like this:

`.sh1 h1:hover` => `.sh1:hover h1`

`.mt h1:hover` => `.mt:hover h1` ...

```css
.sh1:hover h1 {
 background-color: #000;
 -moz-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 transition: .6s ease-in-out;
}

.sh1 {
    background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/140/180/any);
 margin:30px;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
}

.bt {
    background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/140/380/any);
 margin:30px;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
}

.mt {
    background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/240/580/any);
 margin:30px;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
}



.mt:hover h1 {
 background-color: red;
 -moz-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 transition: .6s ease-in-out;
}

.bt:hover h1 {
 background-color: blue;
 -moz-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
 transition: .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="bt"><h1>BIG TITLE</h1></a>
<a href="#" class="mt"><h1>MEDIUM TITLE</h1></a>
<a href="#" class="sh1"><h1>SMALL H1</h1></a>
```